# Autohotkey (ahk) GUI Crosshair Implementation

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

I wanted to create a  fix for this unintended feature ( here's the demo: https://youtu.be/X9qQSk25mTo ) known as Chameleon Effect, Fallout 4. I wanted to create a crosshair implementation from AHK whereas if I hold right click there's a small dot in my screen that can guide during the "Chameleon" effect.

Explanation: If you have the Chameleon effect it turns your character invisible when crouching including your weapon and it's reticle/iron sights, which makes it hard to aim. Aiming down the sight also removes the crosshair like in every modern fps games.

Here's what I wrote

-deleted

Disclaimer: I only learned graphical programming and just started AHK few days ago and I'm not familiar with the syntax (I'm still reading about it)

Was able to write this script, but whenever I run it the script itself creates a new window (the small dot acts a window/tab) and then unfocuses me out of my game and then focuses on the dot. Meaning I can't press anything intended for my game like walking or firing. I tried patching it using WinExist and WinActivate to refocus it on my game but still kinda buggy and sometimes tabs me out of my game occasionally (Using Win command means I would have to also include every game I need to play), I needed a universal fix, allowing me to be able to put it on probably every game I want.

I have an idea how to fix it but I'm at the end of my rope about what syntax to use which begs the question, how do I make it completely ignore the window my script opens, as if it's just running on top my screen? (but also running in the background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool script! This could be useful for a number of games.

I think what you're looking for is the `NoActivate` or `NA` option for `Gui, Show`.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Show

Modify this line and I think it will work as you want:

```
Gui, crosshair:Show , NoActivate
```